# is in python a deep json parsing?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, lib, python-jsons

I have next code:

```
import json
string = b'{"campaign_id":6,"email":"test@test.ru","time":"2024-01-26T06:05:59.852155Z","message":"Submitted Data","details":"{\\"payload\\":{\\"__RequestVerificationToken\\":[\\"CfDJ8EfyW-fedawawdawdwadwadwawadawd-6xqg_ZIdEJBpbAHkDQdNM\\"],\\"__original_url\\":[\\"https://test-test-test.ru/\\"],\\"password\\":[\\"test\\"],\\"qwe\\":[\\"Gg4gTWg\\"],\\"username\\":[\\"test\\"]},\\"browser\\":{\\"address\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"user-agent\\":\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0\\"}}"}'
a = json.loads(string)
```

Problem is not parsing dict by key details.
If you make json.loads, you will see that in key value the inside json cannot be parsed.
How can i parse dict in key "details".

I tried some another librirais. But no success.

Comment: That's because the `details` value is double-encoded. You need to separately decode it a 2nd time. Or fix the JSON at the source.

Comment: is any readyt library for this? Maybe i can some transform string for parsing?

Comment: no errors. Just not parsed dict.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: key "details", value is a dict. Library json.loads doesnt parse the dict. I dont wanna lauch the function again. I want to parse in one laucnch.

Comment: Is it just contained json? `json.loads(a["details"])`?

Comment: but if i imagine situation, that i dont know key names, what will i do?

Comment: The value of `details` is a string, it may contain an JSON object but that's nothing a parser should care about. And I wrote what you have to do already.

Comment: i hope, that the parser exists. Maybe. I dont know. But i hope.

Comment: Its just the json.loads parser. You run it a second time. You have to know that "details" is encoded this way. Remember that when the originator encoded that data, "details" had already been encoded to a string. That encoder sees a string like any other string. nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

The "details" key contains a string representation of a JSON object, which is escaped.
To parse the nested JSON inside the "details" key,

- you need to first decode the string and then
- parse it as JSON.

Try like this

```
import json

string = b'{"campaign_id":6,"email":"test@test.ru","time":"2024-01-26T06:05:59.852155Z","message":"Submitted Data","details":"{\\"payload\\":{\\"__RequestVerificationToken\\":[\\"CfDJ8EfyW-fedawawdawdwadwadwawadawd-6xqg_ZIdEJBpbAHkDQdNM\\"],\\"__original_url\\":[\\"https://test-test-test.ru/\\"],\\"password\\":[\\"test\\"],\\"qwe\\":[\\"Gg4gTWg\\"],\\"username\\":[\\"test\\"]},\\"browser\\":{\\"address\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"user-agent\\":\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0\\"}}"}'
decoded_string = string.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(decoded_string)
details_json = json.loads(data['details'])

print(details_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "details" value appears to be JSON - a string encoding of the dictionary you want. When the outer dict is also encoded, it's just a normal string as far as the encoder is concern. You can unwrap by reversing the steps: Decode the outer dict, then decode the inner.

```
import json
string = b'{"campaign_id":6,"email":"test@test.ru","time":"2024-01-26T06:05:59.852155Z","message":"Submitted Data","details":"{\\"payload\\":{\\"__RequestVerificationToken\\":[\\"CfDJ8EfyW-fedawawdawdwadwadwawadawd-6xqg_ZIdEJBpbAHkDQdNM\\"],\\"__original_url\\":[\\"https://test-test-test.ru/\\"],\\"password\\":[\\"test\\"],\\"qwe\\":[\\"Gg4gTWg\\"],\\"username\\":[\\"test\\"]},\\"browser\\":{\\"address\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"user-agent\\":\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0\\"}}"}'
a = json.loads(string)
a["details"] = json.loads(a["details"])
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this solution can help you call ones loads function

```
import json


class InnerDictEncoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.object_hook, *args, **kwargs)

    def object_hook(self, dct):
        if 'details' in dct:
            dct['details'] = json.loads(dct['details'])
            return dct
        return dct



string = b'{"campaign_id":6,"email":"test@test.ru","time":"2024-01-26T06:05:59.852155Z","message":"Submitted Data","details":"{\\"payload\\":{\\"__RequestVerificationToken\\":[\\"CfDJ8EfyW-fedawawdawdwadwadwawadawd-6xqg_ZIdEJBpbAHkDQdNM\\"],\\"__original_url\\":[\\"https://test-test-test.ru/\\"],\\"password\\":[\\"test\\"],\\"qwe\\":[\\"Gg4gTWg\\"],\\"username\\":[\\"test\\"]},\\"browser\\":{\\"address\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"user-agent\\":\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0\\"}}"}'.decode(encoding='utf-8')
a = json.loads(string, cls=InnerDictEncoder)

print(a)
```